# Is there an online example of using TinyMCE with a print layout like word

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, ckeditor

Is there an online example of using TinyMCE with a print layout like word where you can see the end of each page? Or is there another open source WYSIWYG editor that has a print layout built in?

Comment: What do you mean by print layout?

Comment: How big is a page?  Word was designed to print; TinyMCE was designed to work on a screen.  Such a thing may exist, but I'd reconsider why you're trying to make that leap.

Comment: The end goal of the documents being edited for this use case will be that they are printed. This being said it is important that the user is able to see how their document will look on each page.

Answer (score 3):

TinyMCE is just the layer between the user and whatever process you are using to generate the printed element.  It just generates HTML markup (and that code can be really messy) and you will need to store the HTML in a file or database.  So to generate your "print preview" of the code, you'll need to access the html directly (and display it with print-friendly css).

Check out MarkitUp (http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/).  This should be customizable to meet your print-friendly needs.

Comment: It looks like MarkItUp as well as TinyMCE will both require a good amount of work to get them to display a print layout. And judging from the lack of other answers it seams that such a tool does not currently exist as a library. Thank you for the response, this gives me a good idea of what is currently available.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) the the official example page of Moxiecode. There are several examples, but i fear your use-case is not to be found there.